# Rails 4 can not connect to mysql after deploy

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, deployment

I got some problems with deploying to staging, hopefully anyone could suggest a solution.

So I am deploying **Rails 4** with **Capistrano** to **DO** droplet. I have production/staging branches on different droplets (actually I am deploying staging for the first time and can't get it working).
Deployment went well, I have my app in "current" folder ready. But what I have troubles with is creating database. When I run

> RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake db:create

I get

> Couldn't create database for {"adapter"=>"mysql2", "encoding"=>"utf8",
>   "reconnect"=>false, "database"=>"blabladb", "pool"=>5,
>   "username"=>"root", "password"=>"pass", "host"=>"111.11.11.111"},
>   {:charset=>"utf8", :collation=>"utf8_unicode_ci"}

I go to **production.log** and it says something like

> FATAL Mysql2 Error Can't connect to MySQL server on "111.11.11.111"
>   (111)

I try to connect to mysql from console - everything goes fine. I do not know what the problem could be here.

My database.yml  from **current** folder:

> production:
>       adapter: mysql2
>       encoding: utf8
>       reconnect: false
>       database: blabladb
>       pool: 5
>       username: root
>       password: pass
>       host: 111.11.11.111

Comment: Where have you got that IP address for `host` from?

Comment: Can you connect to the same MySQL instance from the console? Maybe you're connecting to the local instance instead without realizing it.

Comment: @RobinFisher that is dummy IP, in real app it is IP of the droplet

Comment: @tadman sorry, I do not understand what You mean, could You give me more details?

Comment: How are you connecting via the `mysql` command-line tool?

Comment: @tadman I mean I can connect to mysql as root user via "mysql -u root -p"

Comment: That connects to the local server, not a remote one. You'd need to do: `mysql --host=111.11.11.111 --user=root --password=pass blabladb`

Comment: Have you tried to put `host: localhost` in the database.yml file?

Comment: @wchiquito Yes, "host: localhost" did the trick. But I do not understand why, as on my production server I have my actual IP in database.yml and that works as well.
Anyway, thank You. Could You please put the solution with answer to my last question as an answer, so I could accept it.

Comment: It seems an issue in configuring MySQL, try comparing the configuration files (MySQL) of production and staging.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a user corresponding to that IP address in your mysql server. This is the reason why it works with localhost and not with IP address. Open your mysql server at production and check if access is granted to root at IP level.